# Is it possible to use something like @RequestParam for JSON in spring rest services?

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I use Spring boot and i am writing rest services server in Spring
I have a lot of different requestmappings, and i need to accept content in json

I can do that with `@RequestBody` annotation
But in this case i will have a lot of POJO classes for every request and every possible response.

And a lot of JSONs I need to send and receive are very simple - one or two or three values

Is it possible to use something like `@RequestParam("field1_from_my_json")` and `@RequestParam("field2_from_my_json")` for extracting the JSON fields as the request parameters, and not to create the new POJO every time?

Comment: No you cannot as the name already implies those are for request parameters which is something else as getting stuff from a JSON encoded body.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of anything like that which spring offers.
But I have some suggestions, if you will :)

1. You can generate the Spring model classes from the contract (a json
   schema, or swagger spec). Even though this adds classes, at least
   you are not manualluy maintaining it
2. If you are so concerned about too many classes, how about a generic
   class with generic fields (I will strongly discourage this though)

> ```
> public class GenericClass {
>     private String field1;
>     private String field2;
>     private String field3;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the strongly typed nature of POJOs etc you can just use a Map as the `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stuff", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> stuff(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> yourSimpleObject) {
    Map<String,Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    numMap.put("prop1", "val1");
    numMap.put("prop2", "val2");
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(response);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can provide you my example Rest Template, getting user info using Facebook API :

```
String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{id}?fields=first_name,last_name,locale,timezone,gender&access_token={accessToken}", String.class, urlVars);
String locale = JsonPath.read(body, "$.locale");
```

Or if you get json as request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> postWebhook(@RequestBody String body) {
    String locale = JsonPath.read(body, "$.locale");
    [...]
}
```

So I use [Jsonpath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) for it. Response json looks like:

```
{ 
  locale : "en_US";
  ...
}
```

So I extract *locale* just reading this property from json:

```
String locale = JsonPath.read(body, "$.locale");
```